# "Значение не может быть неопределенным"

Tags: c#, vknet

При попытке получить картинки пользователя, получаю: `Значение не может быть неопределенным.`

Ведь, руководствуясь статье: https://vk.com/dev/objects/photo `photo_130` имеет тип `string` и должен вернуть URL ссылку картинки, правильно же? А почему тогда не работает? Дату возвращает правильно.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: может ты попробуешь написать вот так `photo_130` ?

Comment: @Andiskiy, не, в библиотеке VkNet название то чуть-чуть отличается, я же не на шару так написал.

Comment: ставь точку останова и проверь что туда приходит в `getAll` , если там все нормально, то следует искать проблему в листбоксе своем.

Comment: @Andiskiy, этот метод "отладки" мне помог, спасибо. Оказывается возвращает не ссылку, а строку вида `{photo250244712_321821337}`, придется теперь думать как отображать картинку.

Comment: @Andiskiy, не подскажете случайно, вот полученные изображения имеют тип `VkNet.Model.Attachments.Photo` как преобразовать в `string`? Пробовал `ToString`, `Convert.ToString`, ошибок при компиляции нет, но в переменную типа `string` всё равно ничего не записывает, просто пусто.

Comment: я не знаю как ты дебажишь ошибки, но вот [тут](https://vk.com/dev/photos.getAll) есть пример запроса и ответ на него. Ну и еще советую определиться какой метод ты используешь. Если юзаешь метод getAll, то там вообще нет строки `photo_130`, а есть просто `src`.

Comment: @Andiskiy, http://storage7.static.itmages.ru/i/16/1230/h_1483126438_2760006_c7dbfcf164.png

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Этот путь к картинке пустой(налл).

Напиши простой метод который двигается от большего разрешения к меньшему и если тот не нулл -- то возвращает адрес картинки который ты можешь добавлять в свой лист.

```
    public static string GetTheBiggestSizeUrlPhoto(Photo photoObj)
    {
        if (photoObj.PhotoSrc != null)
        {
            return photoObj.PhotoSrc.OriginalString;
        }
        if (photoObj.Photo2560 != null)
        {
            return photoObj.Photo2560.OriginalString;
        }
        if (photoObj.Photo1280 != null)
        {
            return photoObj.Photo1280.OriginalString;
        }
        if (photoObj.Photo807 != null)
        {
            return photoObj.Photo807.OriginalString;
        }
        if (photoObj.Photo604 != null)
        {
            return photoObj.Photo604.OriginalString;
        }
        if (photoObj.Photo130 != null)
        {
            return photoObj.Photo130.OriginalString;
        }

        return photoObj.Photo75.OriginalString;
    }
```

Учись дебажится.

Потом отдельно пишешь метод для скачивания картинки с адреса и можешь достать сам битмап/

```
    public static Bitmap GetPhotoBitmapFromUrl(string url)
    {
        if (url != string.Empty)
        {
            try
            {
                WebRequest request = WebRequest.Create(url);

                WebResponse response = request.GetResponse();

                Stream responseStream = response.GetResponseStream();

                Bitmap bitmapImg = new Bitmap(responseStream);

                return bitmapImg;
            }
            catch (WebException)
            {
            }
        }

        return new Bitmap(1, 1);
    }
```

Comment: Так они все получается null возвращают. Хотя, как писал выше Andiskiy  "ставь точку останова", то показывает `{photo250244712_321821337}`, как же он null тогда?) Непонятно что-то..

Comment: я могу код скинуть :) У меня все работает как часы уже несколько месяцев по даному принципу :)

Comment: Был бы рад взглянуть)

Comment: мой главный совет все тот же: учись дебаджится.

Comment: За совет и код большое спасибо, но в данный момент не врубаюсь в ваш код) Как вызывать метод GetTheBiggestSizeUrlPhoto? Почему там идет условие если не null, а если они все null будут?

Comment: метод `photos.getAll` не возвращает `Photo130` оно доступно в другом методе, просто `photos.get`, для getAll `src`

Comment: Что-то я не нашел метод `photos.get` на сайте VkNet и всё равно мало что понял. В общем, спасибо, завтра попробую свежими мозгами подумать.

Comment: Я бы советовал тебе с таким уровнем начать с чего-то другого. Сам VkNet написан очень и очень криво. Местами что бы некоторые методы заработали мне приходилось писать костыли в самой библиотеке. И довольно сложные даже для меня. А это явно не твой уровень пока что, если не можешь разобратся с на столько простым кодом как мой :) Это просто дружеский совет.

Comment: @Andrew, спасибо, я во всем разобрался)